# Book for exercises

Tags: resource-request

do you know any book for the exercises in Latin.

I'm looking for something similar to Hans Orbergs' exercitia book.

If you know any, please let me know.

Comment: You might get more traction if you explain Orbergs' book to those unfamiliar with it.